# How to create API facade by combining other objects' APIs?

Tags: scala

I have a number of stateless objects in Scala that I would like to combine together into one API -- a kind of facade as follows:

```
object tools {
   // List all methods in toolA

   // List all methods in toolB

   // List all methods in toolC

}
object ToolA { ... }
object ToolB { ... }
object ToolC { ... }
```

Obviously it's annoying to maintain the list in `tools` as the methods in `ToolA`, `ToolB`, and `ToolC` are changing a lot. There is no state in A/B/C and there are no setup parameters.

What are the ways to say...*"make `tools` contain the set of all of the methods in `ToolA`, `ToolB`, and `ToolC`"*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define ToolA, B and C as traits instead

```
trait ToolA {
    //stateless methods in ToolA
}
```

Then you can do

```
object tools extends ToolA with ToolB with ToolC
```

You can also have a helper object only for ToolA, ToolB and ToolC

```
object toolA extends ToolA
object toolB extends ToolB
object toolC extends ToolC
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I suspected: there was some syntax for using "with trait" repeatedly! Java-ism didn't work e.g. extends Foo with A,B,C

Comment: The much-expanded capabilities of `trait`s in Scala is hugely powerful. You should at a minimum be aware that traits are not restricted to defining pure abstract types (with no implementation). They may, in fact, freely mix abstract (unimplemented) and concrete (implemented) values and methods. Their biggest limitation is the absence of constructor parameters.